# Any Microsoft Dataverse database backend for Django?

Tags: sql, django, database, odata, dataverse

I'd like to write a frontend for my Microsoft Dataverse database backend so as to manage Dataverse data easily. Django comes with an easy-to-configure admin which suits my needs fine. I would like to know if there has been any third-party backends for Dataverse already, or I just need to implement the backend by myself because few people care about using Dataverse as the backend for their Django Applications. Craving for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

Django officially supports the following databases:
PostgreSQL,
MariaDB,
MySQL,
Oracle,
SQLite,
also works with sqlserver and mongodb but they are not officially supported.

[Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/)

I personally don't know about dataverse.
I found this and it seems possible:

[pyDataverse](https://pydataverse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

But know that if you have problems and are looking for solutions I don't think there is a sufficient community.
my advice is to choose another database,possibly open source, so you're in the right mood, if you want to use python and its django framework.
Last but not least, check what you can do in production with Dataverse.

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess you have been mistaken with [the "open source web application to share, preserve, cite, explore and analyze research data" developed by Harvard University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataverse) while I'm referring specifically to [Microsoft Dataverse belonging to Microsoft Power Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_Platform#Microsoft_Dataverse).

Comment: @Baytars I'm sorry if I didn't respect your question and allowed myself to give my advice for the database.
However if you need to use DATAVERSE in Django ORM you need a Django specific library with the necessary ODBC drivers. Django is famous for treating databases "Out Of The Box". You can use more than one database in Django by configuring settings.py appropriately. Good luck

Comment: Never mind. I was once confused, too. You came in good time for me to disambiguate.